# A reusable object with an image map or SVG interactivity in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, import, asset-management, interaction

I use Illustrator to make web sites with SVG pages ([ozake.com](http://ozake.com)).

To create animations and menus, I use the **Attributes palette** to add **links** to an object and I use the **SVG Interactivity palette** to add **mouseover/mouseout actions** to object.

I have not been able to find a way to **re-use objects between documents** and **keep the links and SVG interactivity intact.**

Ideally, I would create an AI document called "menu.ai" with all the menu functionality, then place it into each page.

But, when I do that **all the interactivity is stripped out** (AI only places the PDF part of the saved document).

Similarly, when I create a symbol, any SVG-related interactivity is removed.

As a workaround I have copied and pasted all re-used objects between documents and scripted most of the work.

**Is there a way to place or extract an external AI document to preserve the link and interactivity?**

Comment: I suspect the answer is NO and therefore your unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: Yes, but I just got so sick of copying and pasting.